# Calculating time difference in java without using any classes

Tags: java, class, time, difference

EDIT: I'm moved on to other methods which are easier to think of at the moment and will keep this one on hold, if possible.

So, I've been thinking of possible ways of doing this , but I get lost in the middle because it looks like a big mess. The way I see it, I need to use if's inside if's inside if's inside.. etc, and I was thinking if there's a better way of doing it. Keeping in mind that I cannot use classes to do this. Any ideas?

EDIT: I've edited this with the comment I've left below.

"When I said classes, I mean classes like Scanner, Calendar GregorianCalendar, Date, etc. I have a method which has 2 arguments, one the date of entrance and the other the exit date. What I need to do is to calculate the time that has passed between those 2, without using any of those classes. I'm not asking for any code, I'm just asking for some ideas or enlighnment on which way to go, because so far all I've though were of if's, but it looks like a big mess to me."

The arguments are strings.

Comment: How is that you cannot use classes? What does this mean? Not even `Date` class?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without classes?

Comment: Technically, in Java, you cannot do anything without a class ;)

What have you tried? What are you comparing?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "cannot use classes" please?  All Java programs consist of classes, and nothing else.  This is like saying I want to eat lunch without any food.

Comment: The simplest you can do is retrieve `java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()` and muck with that, but that's using a class.  And of course your Java program itself must reside inside a class.

Comment: @jakson Well what is `int i = 10;` then? Only you'd need to create a `main()` method in a... class, and if you'd ever want to output it, you'd need to use a... class.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Is this just as an academic excercise, or would there be an actual purpose? Have you written any code (even pseudocode, for that matter) to do this?

Comment: When I said classes, I mean classes like Scanner, Calendar GregorianCalendar, Date, etc. I have a method which has 2 arguments, one the date of entrance and the other the exit date. What I need to do is to calculate the time that has passed between those 2, without using any of those classes. I'm not asking for any code, I'm just asking for some ideas or enlighnment on which way to go, because so far all I've though were of if's, but it looks like a big mess to me.

Comment: What type are the two arguments?  You say you're not using `Date` or `Calendar`, so just what form DO you have those dates in?

Comment: If you show a bit of what you've got so far and what you've tried, it may be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Best you can do to "calculate time difference without using classes":

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
<Do something>
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;

int milliseconds = (int)(elapsedTime % 1000);
int seconds = (int) ((elapsedTime / 1000) % 60);
int minutes = (int) ((elapsedTime / 60000) % 60);
int hours = (int) (elapsedTime / 1440000);
```

(This is, of course, using the `System` class, and whatever class your program is compiled into.  But I don't know how to reduce it further.)

Answer (score 0):

Without Classes you cant do anything in Java

There are set of libraries to do such kind of operations.

SEE [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: Ah, but those pesky classes that the OP doesn't want to use have found their way into Joda-Time.

Comment: @GriffeyDog This is not what OP wants, it ll helps other